# Sorting Array ,Sorting ArrayList ,using Collections

Tags: java, arrays, string, primitive-types

Ok,still learning Arrays.
  I wrote this code which fills the array named "rand" with random numbers between 0 and 1(   exclusive).
I want to start learning Complexity.
the For loop executes n times (100 times) ,every time it takes O(1) time,so the worse case scenario is O(n),am I right?
Also,I used ArrayList to store the 100 elements and I imported "Collections" and used Collections.sort() method to sort the elements.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
    public class random
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            double[] rand=new double[10];

                    for(int i=0;i<rand.length;i++)
                    {
                        rand[i]=(double) Math.random();
                        System.out.println(rand[i]);
                    }   

                    Arrays.sort(rand);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rand));
        }
    }
```

ArrayList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class random
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Double> MyArrayList=new ArrayList<Double>();


        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {               
            MyArrayList.add(Math.random());
        }

        Collections.sort(MyArrayList);


        for(int j=0;j<MyArrayList.size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println(MyArrayList.get(j));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, the complexity of adding N items is O(N). Sorting will take an additional O(N * log(N)) in most cases according to the docs:

> The sorting algorithm is a tuned quicksort, adapted from Jon L.
>   Bentley and M. Douglas McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function",
>   Software-Practice and Experience, Vol. 23(11) P. 1249-1265 (November
>   1993). This algorithm offers n*log(n) performance on many data sets
>   that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance.

`ArrayList` is still backed by an array, so the complexities will be the same, bar the occasional resizing which is amortized anyway.